# WPF Datagrid - Column Binding related to other columns

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, converters

I have a DataGrid with several Columns. Some of these columns are something like

```
state|Color1|Color2|Color3|...
```

I want to do this:

```
If state==1 => RowForeground = Color1
If state==2 => RowForeground = Color2
If state==3 => RowForeground = Color3
...
```

The very first solution I can think is to use several Data Triggers:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=state}" Value="0">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=color0, Converter={StaticResource str2clrConverter}}"/>                            
</DataTrigger>

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=state}" Value="1">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=color1, Converter={StaticResource str2clrConverter}}"/>                            
</DataTrigger>

<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=state}" Value="2">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=color2, Converter={StaticResource str2clrConverter}}"/>                            
</DataTrigger>

[...]
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multibinding is the way!

Here how I solved:

```
<Setter Property="Foreground">
    <Setter.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource frgConverter}">
            <Binding Path="state"/>

            <Binding Path="color1"/>
            <Binding Path="color2"/>
            <Binding Path="color3"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

And the Converter:

```
public class GridForegroundConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int iColor;
        int nState = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);

        if (nState < 0 || nState > 3)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("State");

        iColor = System.Convert.ToInt32(values[nState + 1]);

        byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(iColor);
        Color color = Color.FromRgb(bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);

        return new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```