# Changing data when itemsource is specified for a datagrid in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid that I am binding to an ObservableCollection of a custom type.  The type has a boolean property, "IsCopying".  The "binding" is done by specifying the ItemSource property of the grid to the ObservableCollection.

I want to change data before it is bound to the grid.  The grid just needs to be a read-only view of the data.  I have changed the column header by using the AutoGeneratingColumn event:

```
if (e.Column.header.ToString() == "IsCopying")
{
   DataGridTextColumn t = new DataGridTextColumn();
   t.header = "Status";
   e.Column = t;
}
```

...which works fine.  I want to do the same thing during the binding of the individual  property to the cell, of each row.  I am thing it would work something like:

```
//NOT REAL CODE!!!!!!!
private void dgItem_CellBinding(object sender, DataGridCellBindingEventArgs e)
{
   MyCustomType theItem = e.(MyCustomType)ObjectGettingBound;
   if (theItem.IsCopying == true)
   {
      e.TypeGettingBound= DataGridCellType.Text //or however this works;
      e.DataToBind = "Working...";
    }else{
      e.TypeGettingBound = DataGridCellType.Text;
      e.DataToBind = "Waiting for command...";
   }
}
```

Hopefully the above makes sense.  I can not find the event for when the individual cell is binding and how to intercept it.  I am sure this is very common but I'm new to this and can't find anything on SO that addresses this particular issue.  Maybe I'm going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

does your custom type implement INotifyPropertyChange?

can you add a public property to your custom type that raises PropertyChange event and exposes the text hat you need?

```
public class MyCustomType: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }

        private bool _IsCopying;

        public bool IsCopying
        {
            get { return _IsCopying; }
            set
            {
                _IsCopying = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsCopyingText");
            }
        }

        public string IsCopyingText
        {
            get
            {
                if(IsCopying) return "Working...";
                else return "Waiting for command...";
            }
        }
}
```

then you bind the column to IsCopyingText property, and if you don't want IsCopying column to show, set its Cancel property to True in AutoGeneratingColumn event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950(v=vs.95).aspx)

to make grid readonly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.isreadonly.aspx

Another way is to use a IValueConverter, like here:

[WPF Datagrid - Column Binding related to other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545703/wpf-datagrid-column-binding-related-to-other-columns)

Comment: No I haven't implemented INotifyPropertyChanged.... unless I'm missing something that has nothing to do with the issue.  I don't care about updates to the grid.  What I'm trying to do is, at "binding time" change what value is sent to the cell.

Comment: Arie,  Sorry, I guess I see what you are getting at.  I would much rather not have to modify the MyCustomType class... that is what is at issue that I am looking at data from the class and just wanting to adjust it at binding time without having to rework the class.  If I could rework the class I'd just change the boolean type to a string or add another property.

Comment: @rune711 then I think the IValueConverter is a way to go for you. This way you don't need to touch your custom class.